# How to retrieve coordinates of the bounding boxes from rendered latex that may contain math expressions?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, pdf, dvi

I'm wondering if there is a path to retrieve bounding boxes of the rendered glyphs (text, math symbols, etc) from latex. `pdftotext` supports partially of that but won't cover non-text glyphs like `\frac{}{}`. Ideally, there should be association produced for the glyphs and their corresponding bounding boxes.

I don't necessarily need to show/visualize those boxes, but only their coordinates. Visualization is helpful in verifying them though.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit: Do you want to show the bounding boxes of different things in the pdf? Or do you want to be able to print these numbers to the log/console? Or do you want to be able to copy text in the pdf and paste it? Or something else?

Comment: Eventually I'd like to print those bounding box specs out into console or file after visualizing their correctness.

Comment: Sorry, still too vague for me. You don't want to [show the boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0BMc.png), do you? Perhaps you can edit your question to make it more clear? I think one reason you got no answer so far is that nobody understood you.

Comment: I made a few edits and hopefully that would clarify things. Essentially I want to have coordinates of those bounding boxes, and visualizing them is a good way to verify their correctness.

Comment: If you produce DVI, you basically produce a series of instructions about boxes.

Comment: @cfr, could you elaborate a bit how to get the boxes out of DVI? Or some pointers how to achieve it?

Comment: Not really. It was just an idea. I think I'd look there, rather than at PDF, in the first instance because at least you know the information has to still be there, which is not necessarily true of the PDF. But you've not provided any code to experiment with.